# Issue while creating pure CSS drop down menu upto level 5

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a drop down menu with pure CSS. It's working fine upto level 4, however when I'm trying to add level 5 somehow its not working as expected.
Here is my code link:http://jsfiddle.net/pX6C6/5/

The CSS part:

```
    #menu table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:80;
    font-size:1em;
}
#menu li a {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
    line-height:29px;
    width:125px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu :hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#5F90D0;
}
#menu :hover > a {
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#5F90D0;
}
#menu ul, #menu :hover ul ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul:hover ul ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul:hover ul:hover ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul:hover ul:hover ul.left {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    width:128px;
}

#menu :hover ul :hover ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul:hover ul, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul :hover ul:hover ul {
    padding:0 3px;
    left:125px;
    top:-3px;
}
#menu :hover ul :hover ul.left, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul.left, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul.left, #menu :hover ul :hover ul :hover ul:hover ul.left {
    padding:0 3px;
    left:-131px;
    top:-3px;
}
#menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#menu li {
    float:left;
    background:#949494;
    margin:3px 3px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly do you expect the menu to behave?

TBH I don't want to try to fix your code, since it looks too complicated.

Simple multilevel menu can be done like this: [jsfiddle.net/jPG3P/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/jPG3P/1/)

```
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu li a {
    display: block;
    background: #aaf;
    height: 25px;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 0;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    background: #ff7e00;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: -26px 0 0 120px;
    position: absolute;
}

#menu li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The other option similar to yours can be achieved by adding this: http://jsfiddle.net/jPG3P/2/

```
#menu>li {
    float: left;
}

#menu>li>ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

And if you add this, it will highlight all chosen items: http://jsfiddle.net/jPG3P/4/

```
li:hover>a {
    background: #ff9f33;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply .I tried modifying my code as per your suggestion, but when I added #menu identifier to CSS code it started breaking. Can you point out where am I going wrong? This is the modified code http://jsfiddle.net/ZPdXP/

Comment: This selector is wrong `ul#menu, li#menu`, `li#menu` makes no sense, there is no li with id menu. Fixed version with some other minor changes: http://jsfiddle.net/ZPdXP/1/